# -n option in if statement in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

What is the `-n` option in `if` statement in Linux?

Let's say there is a code:

```
if [ -n "$variable" ];then break;fi
```

What is it checking about the variable in `if` statement?

Comment: It’s not an option of Linux or `if`, it’s [`[`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: The options are described in `man test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-n checks if the corresponding string variable (in your case $variable) is of non-zero length.

Comment: that means if $variable has 0 length value then it will exit from if statement?

Comment: If $variable has 0 length, nothing after "then" statement will be executed. You can easily see what happens by replacing break with an echo.